# count occurrence of value in multiple fields independently (awk)

Tags: awk

I have seen numerous posts to achieve this task for individual fields, but I am struggling to apply it on multiple field separately.

input:

```
group1|apple|orange|lemon
group1|apple|kiwi|banana
group1|orange|cherry| lemon
group1|apple|orange|pear
```

(The real file has many more fields, so I need to use a loop to process each fields)

output:

```
Field|Fruit|Count
2|apple|3
2|orange|1
3|orange|2
3|kiwi|1
3|cherry|1
4|lemon|2
4|banana|1
4|pear|1
```

What I tried so far, but returns the entire count for all the fields:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; print "Field|Fruit|Count"}
    {
      for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
        a[$i]=$i
        count[$i]++
      }
    }
    END{
      for(j in count) print j OFS count[j]
    }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the field number as part of the key in the `count` array.

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"; print "Field|Fruit|Count"}
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            count[i OFS $i]++;
        }
    }
    END {
        for (j in count) {
            print j, count[j];
        }
    }'
```

Comment: People are so easily impressed.